# Re-render Reactjs component

Tags: reactjs, react-router, js-cookie

I have an application that requires authentication via and api call to the Authentication Server (AS). (AS) will redirect to my application with the information I need to set some browser cookies which would affect what the user can see depending on his/her level of permission.

However, I am unable to get my application to detect the change in cookies and render accordingly. I need to hit the refresh button manually to force the components to look into the cookies and pull out the information.

My question is: how come the methods such as render(), componentDidMount() did not get called when i was redirected back to my react application from the authentication server?

App.js:

```
componentDidMount() {
    console.log('App mounted!');
    const env = process.env.NODE_ENV;
    const code = this.getParameterByName('code');
    const stateID = this.getParameterByName('state');
    const authentication = new Authentication();
    const authorization = new Authorization();

    const sid = Cookies.get('sid'); 

    console.log('sid: ', sid);

    if (sid === undefined) {
      if (code === null || stateID === null) {
        authentication.signin(expressURL, env);
      } else {
        authentication.handleIDToken(expressURL, code, stateID).then(reply => {
          // console.log('Reply: ', reply);

          // let dt = new Date(reply.expiry * 1000).toUTCString();
          Cookies.set('userRole', reply.Role, {path: '/', expiry: new Date(reply.expiry * 1000).toUTCString()});
          Cookies.set('userName', reply.Name, {path: '/', expiry: new Date(reply.expiry * 1000).toUTCString()});
          Cookies.set('sid', reply.SID, {path: '/', expiry: new Date(reply.expiry * 1000).toUTCString()});
        });
      }
    }

    if (sid !== undefined && Cookies.get('apiToken') === undefined) {
      authorization.setDjangoApiToken(expressURL).then(response => {
        if (response === 200) {
          this.initialize();  // Populates my redux stores
        } else {
          this.setState({
            error: response
          });
        }
      });
    }
  }
```

Or did i misunderstand some React lifecycle?

I am using React15 & js-cookies

*** I have an Express.js backend that performs these calls to the authentication server.

Cheers

Comment: Hi AKJ, can you add a simplified code example? From my understanding you are making an API call but not updating the internal state of your React app, and therefore it wouldn't kick off any re-renders.

Comment: @leocreatini I have provided what i think can help to make it easier to understand what I am doing

Answer (score 0):

Here's a couple of options:

1. Force your app to reload with `window.location.reload();`
2. Pass some prop to `componentDidUpdate()` in your App.js and evaluate whether the cookie has been set or not.

Comment: What is the best way to use option(1)? If i merely throw it into the componentDidMount(), it will reload indefinitely. And i cannot find a place to put a conditional check since any of the lifecycle methods doesnt seem to be called when i am redirected to my application

Comment: There might be some sort event thrown that you could catch, but I'm not sure as I'm not really familiar with the stack you're using for auth.